# Поместить пользовательский компонент в ScrollView

Tags: android, java

У меня есть своя вьюшка, в которой переопределяется `onDraw` и с помощью 2D-графики на canvas рисуется мой "компонент". Я хотел бы добавить возможность её скроллить (горизонтально и вертикально). Я переопределил `onMeasure`:

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) { 
  width = MeasureSpec.getSize(width); 
  height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); 
  // в статье вместо этой строки super.onMeasure(width, height); 
  // но так совсем не работает
  setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Код использования скроллера такой:

```
ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(context);
scroller.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroller.setFillViewport(true);
CustomView view = new CustomView(context);
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
scroller.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
scroller.addView(view);
```

Параметры LayoutParams меняю по-разному, но всё равно результата нет.

Этот пример я взял из статьи. Но не совсем понятно:

1. Как быть, если я не могу использовать константу (в примере - 300), потому что моя компонента будет занимать область, оставшуюся от других компонентов (могут быть абсолютно разных размеров). Т.е. может, можно туда поставить `FILL_PARENT`?
2. Размеры пользовательской компоненты могут меняться. Что нужно сделать, чтобы сказать скроллеру, что компонента внутри него изменила размеры?
3. Как заставить скроллеры отображаться? Что здесь пропущено?

Comment: А Вы пробовали добавить ваш компонент в ScrollView? Что происходит?

Comment: Конечно, добавляю. И в добавляемой компоненте переопределяю этот метод.

Comment: Какой именно? onMeasure? 
Я имел ввиду написать разметку в xml, добавить ScrollView, а в него уже ваш компонент. Учтите только, что в ScrollView должен лежать только один дочерний компонент.

Comment: Добавил свой код в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу константы в 300, Вы можете убрать ее и использовать передаваемый в onMeasure() параметр height. FILL_PARENT и WRAP_CONTENT имеют специальные значения, можно и правда попробовать поставить их.
Можно попробовать создавать вашу вьюшку в xml и определить свойство scrollbars(может помочь). 
А вообще, думаю Вам стоит обратить внимание на данный [пример](http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/source/browse/trunk/src/com/deezapps/widget/HorizontalPager.java), либо другой из данного репозитория. По крайней мере, в коде по ссылке переопределяются все нужные вам методы + скроллинг. Используйте как пример, либо найдите другой кастомный компонент(благо на Google Code их хватает).